# Google Sheets - IF cell contains certain a list of text then text values return values

Tags: google-sheets, search

I would the google sheets formula to search for specific words in the same cell, and when it gets a match it will return  those words/values

For example, a cell (K3) contains the following characters: FR, IT, ES, GB, DE, AT, CH, BZ, BQ, CM, CF, CN, AF, AL, AS, BS, BD, BJ, BM, BT, VG ,BI, KH, KY, CK, CU, HT, HN

In F3, I need a formula that will search K3 for  FR, GB, IT, CH, DE, AL. If it finds those characters to return them in F3 or else return "No action required"

Hoping you can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=reduce(,split(F3,", "),lambda(a,c,lambda(z,if(z="","No action required",z))(textjoin(", ",1,{a,xlookup(c,H:H,H:H,)}))))
```

- List of words that need to be searched are listed in `Column H`

[image]